# How can I get Position() using Regex to get the substring?

Tags: mysql, regex, position

I have tried

```
Select Position((Select Binary Name Regexp ' [A-Z]{2} ' from Table in Name) from Table
```

to no effect as part of a larger query.

I am trying to find where embdedded acronyms exist in my table to extract themn e.g.

```
'Eastern Standard Time EST time zone'
```

I need to identify where it is so I can do a substring query to get the three words prior.

db-fiddle.com/f/u3EcFmfetkPVFYMmk8An9t/0

Comment: Describe the task, not your attempt to solve it only.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> select regexp_instr(Term, ' [A-Z]{2}', 1, 1, 0, 'c') as position from Acronyms;
+----------+
| position |
+----------+
|       22 |
+----------+
```

The [REGEXP_INSTR() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-instr) is new in MySQL 8.0, so if you use an older version of MySQL, you must upgrade.

To make the search case-sensitive, I had to add four optional arguments. See the documentation for the meaning of these arguments.

Comment: That looks awesome unfortuneatly I am at 5.6 :| so not sure what I'd break if anything upgrading.

Comment: You might like some Percona blog articles like [How to Upgrade to MySQL 8.0 – Free Course at Percona University Online](https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/09/14/how-to-upgrade-to-mysql-8-0-free-course-at-percona-university-online/) or [Upgrading to MySQL 8? Meet the MySQL Shell Upgrade Checker Utility](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/09/27/mysql-8-shell-upgrade-checker-utility/)

Comment: MySQL 5.6 reached its end-of-life in February 2021, and even 5.7 is due to be EOL by October 2023. The software will continue to work, but there will be no more security patches after the EOL dates. So it would be a good idea to figure out how to upgrade eventually.

Comment: Here's one more! [Percona Utilities That Make Major MySQL Version Upgrades Easier](https://www.percona.com/blog/percona-utilities-that-make-major-mysql-version-upgrades-easier/)